# Model.findById() is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I trying to implement a favorite toggle where it saves the favorites in an array, I create a Schema and a router, the code you can see below the problem is when I try to test it on insomnia I'm getting undefined on my console.log(isFavorite). I don't know what could be wrong.

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    favorites: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Places" }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  });
```

// route

```
router.put("/favorites/:placeId", (req, res) => {

  const userId = "5ebd13df31430045957db8c3";

  User.findById(userId).then( (user) => {

    const isFavorite = user.favorites.find( (favorite) => {
      return favorite === req.params.placeId;
    });

    console.log(isFavorite);
    console.log(req.params.placeId);

    if (isFavorite) {
      User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: userId },
        {
          $pull: { favorites: req.params.placeId },
        },
        {
          new: true,
        })
        .then((user) => res.json(user))
        .catch((err) => res.status(400).json(err));
    } else {
      User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: userId },
        {
          $push: { favorites: req.params.placeId },
        },
        {
          new: true,
        })
        .then((user) => res.json(user))
        .catch((err) => res.status(400).json(err));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey! Is `find` an async function? Then you either should `await` the result: `const isFavorite = await ...` otherwise you log `isFavourite` before it is assigned, so it is correctly ùndefined`.

Answer (score 0):

this chunk is bad:

```
User.findById(userId).then((user) => {
    const isFavorite = user.favorites.find((favorite) => {
      return favorite === req.params.placeId;
    });
```

instead must use populate():

```
let favorites = await User.findById(userId).populate('favorites');
```

and then filter favorites by placeId